# Correct way to try/except using Python requests module?

Tags: python, exception, python-requests, request

```
try:
    r = requests.get(url, params={'s': thing})
except requests.ConnectionError, e:
    print(e)
```

Is this correct? Is there a better way to structure this? Will this cover all my bases?

Answer (score 1347, accepted):

Have a look at the Requests [exception docs](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart.html#errors-and-exceptions).  In short:

> In the event of a network problem (e.g. DNS failure, refused connection, etc), Requests will raise a **`ConnectionError`** exception.
>
> In the event of the rare invalid HTTP response, Requests will raise an **`HTTPError`** exception.
>
> If a request times out, a **`Timeout`** exception is raised.
>
> If a request exceeds the configured number of maximum redirections, a **`TooManyRedirects`** exception is raised.
>
> All exceptions that Requests explicitly raises inherit from **`requests.exceptions.RequestException`**.

To answer your question, what you show will *not* cover all of your bases. You'll only catch connection-related errors, not ones that time out.

What to do when you catch the exception is really up to the design of your script/program. Is it acceptable to exit? Can you go on and try again?  If the error is catastrophic and you can't go on, then yes, you may abort your program by raising [SystemExit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#SystemExit) (a nice way to both print an error and call `sys.exit`).

You can either catch the base-class exception, which will handle all cases:

```
try:
    r = requests.get(url, params={'s': thing})
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:  # This is the correct syntax
    raise SystemExit(e)
```

Or you can catch them separately and do different things.

```
try:
    r = requests.get(url, params={'s': thing})
except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
    # Maybe set up for a retry, or continue in a retry loop
except requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects:
    # Tell the user their URL was bad and try a different one
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    # catastrophic error. bail.
    raise SystemExit(e)
```

---

As [Christian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/456550/christian-long) pointed out:

> If you want http errors (e.g. 401 Unauthorized) to raise exceptions, you can call [`Response.raise_for_status`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.raise_for_status). That will raise an `HTTPError`, if the response was an http error.

An example:

```
try:
    r = requests.get('http://www.google.com/nothere')
    r.raise_for_status()
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
    raise SystemExit(err)
```

Will print:

```
404 Client Error: Not Found for url: http://www.google.com/nothere
```

Comment: Very good answer for dealing with the specifics of the requests library, and also general exception-catching.

Comment: Note that because of a bug in the underlaying urllib3 library, you'll also need to catch `socket.timeout` exceptions if you are using a timeout: https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/1236

Comment: Future comment readers: this was fixed in Requests 2.9 (which bundles urllib3 1.13)

Comment: If you want http errors (e.g. 401 Unauthorized) to raise exceptions, you can call [Response.raise_for_status](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.raise_for_status). That will raise an HTTPError, if the response was an http error.

Comment: Thanks @ChristianLong. I've added that excellent bit of information to my answer.

Comment: The exception list on the [Request website](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#exceptions) isn't complete. You can read the full list [here](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/exceptions.py).

Comment: Is there a way to print out a custom error message when `r.raise_for_status()` returns an error? The default message is kinda scary and I would like to give the user some suggestions on how to avoid error responses.

Comment: @user5359531 Sure. Handle different exceptions and `print` different messages for each one.

Comment: Great answer! Another possibility, if you use the `urllib3` feature to retry on certain return codes, is `requests.exceptions.RetryError`. To do retries, but avoid needing to catch retry failures, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43481165/how-to-access-server-response-when-python-requests-library-encounters-the-retry

Comment: upvoted! so lets say this api call is done inside a method which is basically your API wrapper, what do you do? return the exception from the except clause to be handled at a higher level, use the logger.warn or something like that? print a string message which i believe is the wrong way to do things

Comment: @PirateApp Good question. It's up to you, but I would wrap and re-raise the requests exceptions. A library shouldn't write diagnostic information to stdout/stderr. Take a look at some other API wrappers like python-gitlab.

Comment: If you need the status code from the response in your exception handling, you can get it from `exception.response.status_code`.

Answer (score 203):

One additional suggestion to be explicit. It seems best to go from specific to general down the stack of errors to get the desired error to be caught, so the specific ones don't get masked by the general one.

```
url='http://www.google.com/blahblah'

try:
    r = requests.get(url,timeout=3)
    r.raise_for_status()
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as errh:
    print ("Http Error:",errh)
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as errc:
    print ("Error Connecting:",errc)
except requests.exceptions.Timeout as errt:
    print ("Timeout Error:",errt)
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
    print ("OOps: Something Else",err)

Http Error: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: http://www.google.com/blahblah
```

vs

```
url='http://www.google.com/blahblah'

try:
    r = requests.get(url,timeout=3)
    r.raise_for_status()
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
    print ("OOps: Something Else",err)
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as errh:
    print ("Http Error:",errh)
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as errc:
    print ("Error Connecting:",errc)
except requests.exceptions.Timeout as errt:
    print ("Timeout Error:",errt)     

OOps: Something Else 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: http://www.google.com/blahblah
```

Comment: is this valid syntax for post too?

Comment: @ScipioAfricanus yes.

Comment: What would be the exception for `Max retries exceeded with url:`? I've add all exceptions to the exception list but it is still not handled.

Comment: @theking2 Try urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError or requests.exceptions.RetryError

Comment: @theking2 try requests.ConnectionError, it will ork

Comment: `ConnectionError` and `Timeout` are subclasses of `RequestException`. In the current form these will never be handled, as `RequestException` takes precedence (it's first on the list).

Answer (score 50):

Exception object also contains original response `e.response`, that could be useful if need to see error body in response from the server. For example:

```
try:
    r = requests.post('somerestapi.com/post-here', data={'birthday': '9/9/3999'})
    r.raise_for_status()
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
    print (e.response.text)
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's a generic way to do things which at least means that you don't have to surround each and every `requests` call with `try ... except`:

## Basic version

```
def requests_call(method, url, **kwargs):
    # see the docs: if you set no timeout the call never times out! A tuple means "max 
    # connect time" and "max read time"
    DEFAULT_REQUESTS_TIMEOUT = (5, 15) # for example
    # but the coder can specify their own of course:
    if 'timeout' not in kwargs:
        kwargs['timeout'] = DEFAULT_REQUESTS_TIMEOUT
    try:
        response = requests.request(method, url, **kwargs)
    except BaseException as exception:
        # anticipate giant data string: curtail for logging purposes
        if 'data' in kwargs and len(kwargs['data']) > 500: 
            kwargs['data'] = f'{kwargs["data"][:500]}...'
        logger.exception(f'method |{method}|\nurl {url}\nkwargs {kwargs}')
        raw_tb = traceback.extract_stack()
        msg = 'Stack trace:\n' + ''.join(traceback.format_list(raw_tb[:-1]))
        logger.error(msg)
        return (False, exception)
    return (True, response)
```

NB

1. Be aware of [`ConnectionError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ConnectionError) which is a builtin, nothing to do with the class [`requests.ConnectionError`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.ConnectionError)*. I assume the latter is more common in this context but have no real idea...
2. When examining a non-`None` returned exception, `requests.RequestException`, the superclass of all the `requests` exceptions (including `requests.ConnectionError`), is not <s>"`requests.exceptions.RequestException`"</s> according to [the docs](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#exceptions). Maybe it has changed since [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16511493/595305).**
3. Obviously this assumes a logger has been configured.
4. It is necessary to include in the `except` block both `logger.exception()` and `logger.error()`, with the latter printing the call stack up to the function. In fact `logger.exception` shows the call stack from here to point of failure, but tells you nothing about the call stack which called this function.

*I looked at the source code: `requests.ConnectionError` subclasses the single class `requests.RequestException`, which subclasses the single class `IOError` (builtin)

**However at the bottom of [this page](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#errors-and-exceptions) you find "requests.exceptions.RequestException" at the time of writing (2022-02)... but it links to the above page: confusing.

---

Usage is very simple:

```
success, deliverable = requests_call('get',
    f'http://localhost:9200/my_index/_search?q={search_string}')
```

First you check `success`: if it's `False` something funny has happened and `deliverable` will be an exception which has to be acted on in some way depending on context. If `success` is `True` then `deliverable` will be a [Response](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response) object.

## Advanced version, when json object is expected to be returned

### (... potentially sparing a great deal of boilerplate!)

A couple of things are tedious with regard to the above: 1) how to stipulate that only one or more status codes are acceptable? 2) how to specify that the JSON dict returned must contain a certain structure of keys and perhaps subdictionaries? In the case of Elasticsearch, for example, you often have JSON objects returned and it is tedious to check that all the keys are actually present before obtaining the values for them.

This is therefore built on the above simple function.

```
def process_json_request(url, method='get', ok_status_codes=200, required_dict=None, **kwargs):
    if required_dict != None and type(required_dict) != dict:
        raise Exception(f'required_dict must be None or dict, not {type(required_dict)} ({required_dict})')
    # NB `ok_status_codes` can either be a list or an int (or None: "any status code acceptable"!
    ok_codes_int = isinstance(ok_status_codes, int)
    ok_codes_list = isinstance(ok_status_codes, list)
    if ok_status_codes != None and (not ok_codes_int) and (not ok_codes_list):
        raise Exception(f'ok_status_codes must be None, list or int, ' +\
             f'not {type(ok_status_codes)} ({ok_status_codes})') 
    success, deliverable = requests_call(method, url, **kwargs)
    if not success:
        deliverable.failure_reason = 'requests_call returned False: deliverable is Exception'
        deliverable.failure_code = 1
        return (False, deliverable)
    response = deliverable
    if ok_status_codes != None and ((ok_codes_list and (response.status_code not in ok_status_codes)) \
        or (ok_codes_int and (response.status_code != ok_status_codes))):
            response.failure_reason = f'unacceptable status code: {response.status_code}'
            response.failure_code = 2
            return (False, response)
    try:
        delivered_json_dict = response.json()
    except requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError:
        response.failure_reason = f'Response body did not contain valid json'
        response.failure_code = 3
        return (False, response)
    def check_dictionary_key_values(required_dict, comparison_dict):
        all_checks_passed = True
        for key, value in required_dict.items():
            if key not in comparison_dict:
                logger.error(f'key absent: {key}')
                all_checks_passed = False
                break
            if type(required_dict[key]) == dict:
                sub_comparison_dict = comparison_dict[key]
                if type(sub_comparison_dict) != dict:
                    logger.error(f'key which yields subdictionary in required does not in comparison: {sub_comparison_dict}')
                    all_checks_passed = False
                    break
                if not check_dictionary_key_values(required_dict[key], sub_comparison_dict):
                    all_checks_passed = False
                    break
            # if a value of "None" is given for a key this means "can be anything"
            elif value != None and comparison_dict[key] != value:
                logger.error(f'key {key} was found as expected but value {value} was not found, instead: {comparison_dict[key]}')
                all_checks_passed = False
                break
        return all_checks_passed
    if not check_dictionary_key_values(required_dict, delivered_json_dict):
        response.failure_reason = f'delivered JSON\n{json.dumps(delivered_json_dict, indent=2)}\n' +\
            f' did not satisfy required_dict\n{json.dumps(required_dict, indent=2)}'
        response.failure_code = 4
        return (False, response)
    return (True, response)
```

**Example use 1:**

```
required_dict = {
    'found': True,
    '_source': {
        'es_version': None,
    },
    # 'cats_and_dogs': 'shanty town',
}
success, deliverable = process_json_request(f'{url_for_specific_index}/_doc/1', required_dict=required_dict)    
if not success:    
    logger.error(f'failed to get Ldoc 1 from index... deliverable.failure_reason:\n{deliverable.failure_reason}')
    ...
returned_dict = deliverable.json()
es_version_from_status_doc = returned_dict['_source']['es_version']
```

If I uncomment the "cats_and_dogs" line it returns `success==False` because this supposedly required key is missing. Conversely, if the required_dict check passes you can be sure that "_source" and "es_version" will not produce nasty `KeyError`s. You also know that key "found" had the value `True`.

NB the `required_dict` stipulating keys and values can be a `dict` nested to any depth; and a value "None" means "value can be anything but at least check that the key is present at this location in the delivered dict". 
It is also possible to make the code cope with `list`s of `dict`s in the recursive function `check_dictionary_key_values` but this makes things a bit too complicated to include here, and will arguably be a very marginal requirement.

**Example use 2:**

This uses a `requests` method other than "get" and, because it creates a new resource, the status code should be 201, not 200. NB the parameter `ok_status_codes` can either be an `int` or a `list` (or indeed `None`, meaning "any status code").

```
data = {...}
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
success, deliverable = process_json_request(f'{ES_URL}{INDEX_NAME}/_doc/1', 
    'put', data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers, ok_status_codes=201)
if not success:    
    logger.error(f'... {deliverable.failure_reason}')
    ....
```