# Python requests - Exception Type: ConnectionError - try: except does not work

Tags: python, url, python-requests, connection, python-2.x

I am using a webservice to retrieve some data but sometimes the url is not working and my site is not loading. Do you know how I can handle the following exception so there is no problem with the site in case the webservice is not working?

```
Django Version: 1.3.1 
Exception Type: ConnectionError
Exception Value: 
HTTPConnectionPool(host='test.com', port=8580): Max retries exceeded with url:
```

I used

```
try:
   r = requests.get("http://test.com", timeout=0.001)
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:    # This is the correct syntax
   print e
   sys.exit(1)
```

but nothing happens

Comment: I'm not sure but shouldn't it be `except requests.exceptions.RequestException, e:`? also you are saying you have `ConnectionError` as an exception but i don't see that you catch this specific exception...

Comment: well because I am new to python I found the answer from here :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511337/correct-way-to-try-except-using-python-requests-module

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You should not exit your worker instance `sys.exit(1)`
Furthermore you 're catching the wrong Error.

What you could do for for example is:

```
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError
try:
   r = requests.get("http://example.com", timeout=0.001)
except ConnectionError as e:    # This is the correct syntax
   print e
   r = "No response"
```

In this case your program will continue, setting the value of `r` which usually saves the response to any default value

Comment: Sorry did not see that you are catching the wrong error: You re getting a ConnectionError, so you need to catch this one (see edited answer)

Comment: It works! thank you very much! But I used 

     except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:

Comment: ConnectionError is also the name of a built-in error type - how can this be a widely used package when they have such horrible naming practices? Neither str nor repr gives any indication that the class isn't the built-in one. It doesn't even inherit from the built-in ConnectionError, it inherits from OSError instead (which the real built-in one also does).