# Socket-timeout: timed out python requests

Tags: python-requests, socket-timeout-exception

Using the `requests` python lib, I make a GET request, and handle Timeout exceptions (as well as other exceptions I don't show here) like

```
import requests
timeout1=20
timeout2=40

try:
    #first attempt
    resp = requests.get(base_url+resource, params=payload, headers=headers,
    timeout=timeout1)
except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
    #timed out, retry once
    try:
       resp = requests.get(base_url+resource, params=payload, headers=headers,
       timeout=timeout2)
       return resp.json()
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
       #Still failed; return error code
       return -1
```

This works fine most of the time, however sometimes my program just completely exits with the error `socket.timeout: timed out`, instead of throwing the `requests.exceptions.Timeout` and this being caught and dealt with.

Why is the requests lib behaving like this? How should I handle this?

Comment: Did you find the answer for this issue?

Comment: Here is the Answer:try:
        data = sock.recv(256)
    except socket.timeout:
        data="NO RESPONSE"

Answer (score 2):

Answer:

```
try:
    data = sock.recv(256)
except socket.timeout:
    data="NO RESPONSE"
```

It won't exit!

Answer (score 2):

I think this is an issue of the urllib3 that requests uses:

https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/1236

You'll have to catch that socket.timeout error.
(based on jb's comment at [Correct way to try/except using Python requests module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511337/correct-way-to-try-except-using-python-requests-module))