# Printing out errors with Requests library

Tags: python, python-requests

I've been reading through http://www.mobify.com/blog/http-requests-are-hard/ , which discusses various types of errors which can be encountered with a request. The article focuses on catching each one. I would like to simply print out the error type whenever any error occurs. In the article , one example is:

```
url = "http://www.definitivelydoesnotexist.com/"

try:
    response = request.get(url)
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
    print "These aren't the domains we're looking for."
```

Is there a way to rewrite the last 2 lines in pseudocode as:

```
except requests.ANYERROR as e:
    print e
```

Comment: `except Exception as e:print(e.message)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16511493/119527):

> All exceptions that Requests explicitly raises inherit from **`requests.exceptions.RequestException`**.

So this should catch everything:

```
try:
    response = requests.get(url)
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print e
```

Comment: This won't catch a ValueError though, `data = response.json()`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Um, yeah, because that line of code is no where in the original post.

Comment: You should have a read of the blog

Comment: One should expect a completely different class of errors when making an HTTP request and when interpreting the text contained in the response. They're totally separate things. Catching `Exception` is never a good idea IMO, except at a top-level exception handler who's going to log and exit, or make a crash dump, etc.

Comment: Besides, a two-second look at [the docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) indicates that `.json()` can raise a `ValueError`.

Comment: where did I say it could not raise a ValueError? If it is only about requests then you should mark it as a dupe.

Comment: I will delete my answer and dupe it

Answer (score 1):

All of the requests exceptions inherit from `requests.exceptions.RequestException`, so you can:

```
try:
    ....
    ....
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    # Do whatever you want to e
    pass
```

Comment: This is *exactly* what I posted 4 minutes prior. Duplicating answers just clutters up the site.

Comment: You are correct. By the time I did the post you already posted yours.