# Get short version of error message with requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm using requests and I need a shortened description of the exception,

```
try:
    resp = requests.get(url)
except Exception, e:
    data['error'] = str(e)
```

e.g for a connection error, `str(e)` becomes `('Connection aborted.', error(61, 'Connection refused'))`

I want to retrieve only the `Connection aborted.` part.

According to the document of `Exception` class, the `e.strerror` should work, but `print (e.strerror)` shows `None`

Any ideas?

Comment: `except Exception,e: if "Connection aborted" in e : #your exception` because `exception` returned `string`, can't handle string as `Exception class` !

Answer (score 1):

The `Exception` class is the base class of all user-defined exceptions (it a recommandation).

This class inherits the `BaseException` which has  a [`args`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.BaseException) attributes.
This attribute is defined as follow:

> **args**
>
> The tuple of arguments given to the exception constructor. Some built-in exceptions (like OSError) expect a certain number of arguments and assign a special meaning to the elements of this tuple, while others are usually called only with a single string giving an error message.

If the error message is in `args[0]`, you can try:

```
try:
    resp = requests.get(url)
except Exception as e:
    data['error'] = e.args[0]
```

Your are not speaking of the standard exception, because `print (e.strerror)` should raise `AttributeError`.

For your answer, you ought to consider the answer of this qestion: [Correct way to try/except using Python requests module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511337/correct-way-to-try-except-using-python-requests-module?answertab=votes#tab-top)

All Requests exceptions inherit [`requests.exceptions.RequestException`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/_modules/requests/exceptions/), which inherits `IOError`.

About `IOError`, the documentation says:

> **exception EnvironmentError**
>
> The base class for exceptions that can occur outside the Python system: IOError, OSError. **When exceptions of this type are created with a 2-tuple**, the first item is available on the instance’s *errno* attribute (it is assumed to be an error number), and the second item is available on the *strerror* attribute (it is usually the associated error message). The tuple itself is also available on the args attribute.

But `RequestException` doesn't seems to be created with a 2-tuple, so *strerror* is `None`.

**EDIT: add some examples:**

If you have `HTTPError`, the original message is in `args[0]`. See this sample of code in `requests.models.Response.raise_for_status`:

```
if http_error_msg:
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
```

If you have `ConnectionError`, the `args[0]` contains the original error. See this sample in `requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter.send`:

```
except (ProtocolError, socket.error) as err:
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
```

It’s the same for `ProxyError`, `SSLError`, `Timeout`: `args[0]` contains the original error.

...

Browse the source code in the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/tree/master/requests).

**One solution could be:**

```
try:
    resp = requests.get(url)
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
    data['error'] = e.args[0]
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    cause = e.args[0]
    data['error'] = str(cause.args[0])
```

Comment: `str(e.args[0])` is the same as `str(e)`, still a long description

Comment: You have to dig deeper: what's the `type(e.args[0])`?

Answer (score 0):

What I've found that works is `e.args[0].reason.args[-1]`

Two example results are *"Connection to 24.31.141.45 timed out. (connect timeout=10)"* or *"Tunnel connection failed: 503 Too many open connections"*.