# Renaming the file downloaded with Python Requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

How can I replace the name of `pdf` file which is downloaded with Python Requests?

I want to save it as `Manual_name1.pdf` not as `Elkinson%20Jeffrey.pdf`

CSV file looks like:

```
Manual_name1 https://www.adndrc.org/diymodule/doc_panellist/Elkinson%20Jeffrey.pdf
Manual_name2 http://www.parliament.bm/uploadedFiles/Content/House_Business/Presentation_of_Papers_and_of_Reports/PCA%20Report%209262014.pdf
manual_name3 http://www.ohchr.org/Documents/HRBodies/OPCAT/elections2016/HaimoudRamdan.pdf
```

My current code:

```
import os
import csv
import requests

write_path = 'C:\\Users\\hgdht\\Desktop\\Downloader_Automation'  # ASSUMING THAT FOLDER EXISTS!

with open('Links.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for link in spamreader:
        if not link:
            continue
        print('-'*72)
        pdf_file = link[0].split('/')[-1]
        with open(os.path.join(write_path, pdf_file), 'wb') as pdf:
            try:
                # Try to request PDF from URL
                print('TRYING {}...'.format(link[0]))
                a = requests.get(link[0], stream=True)
                for block in a.iter_content(512):
                    if not block:
                        break

                    pdf.write(block)
                print('OK.')
            except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:  # This 
will catch ONLY Requests exceptions
                print('REQUESTS ERROR:')
                print(e)  # This should tell you more details about the error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
pdf_file = link[0].split('/')[-1]
```

use the specific column from the csv file:

```
pdf_file = link[1]  # (assuming the file name is in the second column)
```

If the file name is in the first column, you should use

```
pdf_file = link[0]  # (assuming the file name is in the first column)
# OR
import time  # put this in the beginning of your script
pdf_file = '{}-{}.pdf'.format(link[0], int(time.time()))
# file name will look like: "name-1495460691.pdf"
```

but then you will have to change the reference to the link itself when calling it with requests:

```
a = requests.get(link[1], stream=True)  # (assuming the link is in the second column)
```

Comment: its worked. But,its save without any `filetype`  and if I have 2 or 3 same name in column 1 it replaces the file again and again + how can I put `timestamp` in filename so it doesn't replace file with same name. @errata

Comment: @WarLock Of course it will replace the file with same name :) You have to ensure that all names are unique. That is a "feature" of each and every OS... I updated my answer with adding timestamp to each file name.

Comment: In case we have multiple links in Column B, C,D too in front of same `manual_name` and save that with save name . How can we read that link too. @errata

Comment: @WarLock Each row from your file will be a [Python list](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html) and you can access elements just like in any other list. Also, please avoid extensive commenting on questions/answers because that's not StackOverflow purpose ([read on bottom about when you should/shouldn't comment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)). Either ask a new question or do research properly before asking ;)

Comment: pardon me. Next time I will keep in mind. :) @errata

Comment: @WarLock No problem! Happy coding! ;)