# I'm trying to make a program in python that downloads files from a link, and moves it to a specific folder

Tags: python, macos, terminal, download, file-transfer

As said in the title, I'm trying to write a script in python 2.7 that downloads files off of a link and moves it to a specific folder. I'm doing this using `raw_input` and the os module. But the `raw_input` for the `fileLocation` variable isn't registering for the `os.system()` operation.

I've attempted to instead use two different methods, both use the command line. The first involves using the `mv` operation in an `os.system()` operation. The exact code is `os.system('mv {} {}'.format(fileName, fileLocation))`. The other runs a `cd` operation through the command line in an attempt to change the download location.

Here is the code:

```
link = raw_input('Link: ')
fileLocation = raw_input('Input File Location: ')
os.system('cd {}'.format(fileLocation)) 
os.system('curl -O {}'.format(link))
# os.system('mv {} {}'.format(fileName, fileLocation))
```

The output is clean and shows no errors. What I want to happen is for the file to be downloaded, and then immediately moved to the specified folder using the `raw_input` operation in fileLocation on line 2, but the file is instead downloaded and kept in the home folder for my user profile.

Comment: Why do you try with wget instead that has already a -O switch to select the destination folder.

Comment: @Marco I didn't actually know about that. Although checking it out it won't work for me. I use a Macbook my school gave me. Which means I don't have access to admin, so I can't use brew.

Comment: @Goyo Thats the point of the code on line three and the commented out code on line five.

Comment: If you are only just learning the basics, you should probably ignore Python 2, and spend your time on the currently recommended and supported version of the language, which is Python 3.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35277128/why-does-not-os-systemcd-mydir-work-and-we-have-to-use-os-chdirmydir-ins

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44082209/renaming-the-file-downloaded-with-python-requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with this line:

```
os.system('cd {}'.format(fileLocation))
```

You want to change it to:

```
os.chdir(fileLocation)
```

Your original code creates a subprocess to execute the "cd" command but doesn't actually change the directory of your current process. You might want to look at [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431684/how-do-i-change-directory-cd-in-python) for how to change directory and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21406887/subprocess-changing-directory) for an explanation to why `os.system('cd <something>')` doesn't change directory

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because command passed in `os.system` is executed in a subshell. When `os.system` is returned it loses the change made by `cd`.

The solution is to either run those command in same os.system call

```
os.system('cd {}; curl -O {}'.format(fileLocation, link))
```

Comment: Of course, the proper solution is to use Python to download the link. See `requests` and all that.

Comment: Actually `open` can download.