# Python: Using requests and a loop with exception error to check if url exists

Tags: python, python-requests

just wondered if somebody could help me tweak this loop:

I am trying to establish if url's exist but the loop is getting stuck when a url doesn't exist (due to the error of trying to find an non-existent url).

I have added in an exception clause but it is throwing an error :(

Any help is much appreciated!

```
Does_Exist = []
for i in range (0, len(df),1):
   X=[]
   url = df.iloc[i][0] + df.iloc[i][1]
   ret = requests.head(url)  
   except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError 
   if ret.status_code == 200: 
       X = 'Yes' 
       break
   else: 
       X = 'No'
   Does_Exist.append(X)
```

This is the error message:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.bspretail.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000222ABC46470>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',))
```

Comment: Where is your `try` block?

Comment: What is the line `except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError` supposed to be doing?

Comment: V new to python, what is a try block? I will do some research and add. Thanks!

Comment: I thought it would except the error that I am having i.e. when that error is recorded rather than break my loop it would skip it

Comment: without try how will it go to except block. Just google try catch block in python and try that

Comment: Perfect will do! Thanks for all your input

Comment: Please check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511337/correct-way-to-try-except-using-python-requests-module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with a Try/Except structure:

```
    Does_Exist = []
    for i in range (0, len(df),1):
       X=[]
       try:
          url = df.iloc[i][0] + df.iloc[i][1]
          ret = requests.head(url)  
          X = 'Yes' 
       except:
         X = 'No'
       Does_Exist.append(X)
```