# Catch proxy errors on requests python

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests

I'm new on python so I'm having some trouble. I'm trying to build a tool that posts data to an external server with proxy. I have it working, but the problem is I don't know how to catch the proxy connection error and print something else. The code I wrote is:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.11) Gecko/2009060215 Firefox/3.0.11",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}
proxies = { 
    "https": "https://244.324.324.32:8081",
}
data = {"test": "test"}
r = requests.post("https://example.com/page", proxies=proxies, json=data, headers=headers)
print(r.text)
```

How can I print, for example "Proxy Connection Error", when the proxy is dead (not connecting/working) or something like this. This is my first time using python so I'm having trouble.

Thank You

Comment: Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511337/correct-way-to-try-except-using-python-requests-module/47007419

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can use a try/except block to catch a connection error:

```
try:
  r = requests.post("https://example.com/page", proxies=proxies, json=data, headers=headers)
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
  print "Proxy Connection Error"
print(r.text)
```

In the code above, if `requests.post` raises a `ConnectionError`, the `except` block will catch it and print out the `Proxy Connection Error` message.

Comment: This catches more than just proxy errors.

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer didn't work for me.
I had to use `requests.exceptions.ProxyError`, i.e.:

```
try:
    req = requests.post(...)
except requests.exceptions.ProxyError as err:
    print("Proxy Error", err)
```

Answer (score 0):

İf you dont know the exception error, You can do run this first

```
try:
    req = requests.post(...)
except requests.exceptions.ProxyError as err:
    print(sys.exc_info()[0])
```

This gives you the error name, and then you can add your code this err.
(Sometimes you need to import the exception error.)