# How to make requests keep trying to connect to url regardless of exception from where it left off in the list?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, api-design

I have a list of IDs that I am passing into a URL within a for loop:

```
L = [1,2,3]
lst=[]
for i in L:
    url = 'URL.Id={}'.format(i)
    xml_data1 = requests.get(url).text
    lst.append(xml_data1)
    time.sleep(1)
    print(xml_data1)
```

I am trying to create a try/catch where regardless of the error, the request library keeps trying to connect to the URL from the ID it left off on from the list (`L`), how would I do this?

I setup this try/catch from this answer ([Correct way to try/except using Python requests module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511337/correct-way-to-try-except-using-python-requests-module))

However this forces the system to exit.

```
try:
    for i in L:
        url = 'URL.Id={}'.format(i)
        xml_data1 = requests.get(url).text
        lst.append(xml_data1)
        time.sleep(1)
        print(xml_data1)
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print (e)
    sys.exit(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the `try-except` block in a loop and only `break` the loop when the request does not raise an exception:

```
L = [1,2,3]
lst=[]
for i in L:
    url = 'URL.Id={}'.format(i)
    while True:
        try:
            xml_data1 = requests.get(url).text
            break
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            print(e)
    lst.append(xml_data1)
    time.sleep(1)
    print(xml_data1)
```

Comment: This is beautiful thank you so much, but how does this keep trying to reconnect?

Comment: It does so with an infinite `while` loop that only breaks when `requests.get` doesn't raise an exception. If an exception is raised, then it prints the exception and goes into the next iteration of the `while` loop, which makes a request again.