# Capturing Response Body for a HTTP Error in python

Tags: python, python-requests

Need to capture the response body for a HTTP error in python. Currently using the python request module's raise_for_status(). This method only returns the Status Code and description. Need a way to capture the response body for a detailed error log.

Please suggest alternatives to python requests module if similar required feature is present in some different module. If not then please suggest what changes can be done to existing code to capture the said response body.

Current implementation contains just the following:

```
resp.raise_for_status()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "capture"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do something like below, which returns the content of the response, in unicode.

```
response.text
```

or

```
try:
    r = requests.get('http://www.google.com/nothere')
    r.raise_for_status()
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
    print(err)
    sys.exit(1) 
# 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: http://www.google.com/nothere
```

here you'll get the full explanation on how to handle the exception. please check out [Correct way to try/except using Python requests module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511337/correct-way-to-try-except-using-python-requests-module)

Comment: To state this more clearly, and maybe what has been missed: the error object has `.request` and `.response` attributes that that make it easy to get the transfer details.  `err.response.content` is what is needed.

Answer (score 8):

I guess I'll write this up quickly.  This is working fine for me:

```
try:
  r = requests.get('https://www.google.com/404')
  r.raise_for_status()
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
  print(err.request.url)
  print(err)
  print(err.response.text)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can log `resp.text` if `resp.status_code >= 400`.

Answer (score 0):

There are some tools you may pick up such as Fiddler, Charles, wireshark.

However, those tools can just display the body of the response without including the reason or error stack why the error raises.