# What is wrong with my Python code and how can I fix it?

Tags: python, python-requests, ping

Here is my code

```
import requests
ping = requests.get('http://example.com')
ping.status_code

if ping.status_code==200:
    print ("Online")
else:
    print ("Offline")
```

It pings `http://example.com`. When the website is online it successfully prints `Online`. when the website is offline, I want it to print `Offline` but instead it is showing me a huge error message ends with this line

```
Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fd3f17372e8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))
```

How can I fix it to successfully print `Offline` if the website is offline?

Comment: I would think you need to use a try catch, and if you catch an exception you know it is offline, otherwise it is online

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct way to try/except using Python requests module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511337/correct-way-to-try-except-using-python-requests-module)

Comment: what about `try/catch`?

Comment: You might want to wrap your call to the `get` function inside a `try-except` block to handle this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting an error on request itself.

```
ping = requests.get('http://example.com')
```

So you don't get a status code if server didn't respond you.
If you want to check if host is down it's worth using exception handling so when request fails your script doesn't go down with an error. Following code should work.

```
import requests
try:
    ping = requests.get('http://example.com')
    print ("Online")
except:
    print ("Offline")
```

Comment: always welcome. worth saying that with this particular script - if website responds with any error (like 500, 404 etc) script will still respond with "Online". So you probably should still include your status_code checks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by modifying your code as below:

Adding `try` and `except` mechanism.

```
import requests
try:
    ping = requests.get('http://example.com')
    ping.status_code

    if ping.status_code==200:
        print ("Online")
    else:
        print ("Offline")
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
    print("Offline")
```