# How to handle exception with request.post() method in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I am using the following code

```
def request_task(url, data, headers):

        try:
            re = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers)
            re.raise_for_status()

        except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
            print (e.response.text)
```

I am able to handle the http error  but not able to to handle connection errors 
How can i modify my code to handle the types connection error ?
Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct way to try/except using Python requests module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511337/correct-way-to-try-except-using-python-requests-module)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can catch the connection error with `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError`

But i don't recommend using too many excepts unless you specifically want to. Here my recommend to catch the exceptions if you using try catch:

```
try:
   re = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers)
   re.raise_for_status()

except Exception as e:
   print(e)
```