# Correct way to catch Python exception for requests ConnectionError

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I'm trying to validate some urls that are passed to me.  I want to make sure that they resolve to an existing website.  In the process, I've coded:

```
try:
   logoStatus = requests.request('GET', logo)
   feedStatus = requests.request('GET', feed)
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
```

Rather than stopping at the exception handler, the code stops and displays the following:

> Exception has occurred: ConnectionError
> HTTPConnectionPool(host='some.web.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded
> with url: / (Caused by
> NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at
> 0x7f33d102f978>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name
> or service not known',))

I referred to [Correct way to try/except using Python requests module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511337/correct-way-to-try-except-using-python-requests-module) in trying to code this, but, it doesn't seem to work for me.

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Works fine for me. try the following code to interact with your exception


`try:
    logoStatus = requests.request('GET', logo)
except Exception as e:
    print(type(e)) # or set a breakpoint and investigate`
Alternatively - provide some extra details (what url, python version, requests version, etc)

Comment: @Y.R. Thanks for the response.  I'm using python3 (3.6) and requests 2.25.1.  I'm debugging in Visual Studio Code.  No matter what I try, the ConnectionError is ignored.  The url is not a valid url.  That's the purpose of this code.  I'm trying to warn the user that he has entered a url that does not resolve to an actual site.

Comment: I dug deeper.  This is a problem with the way Visual Studio code handles this exception.  I ran the code external to VSC and it ran successfully and trapped the exception.

Comment: Makes sense. I tested it using python in my cmd. You should add a comment describing the solution, other people may encounter the same thing