# HTTPError + Request

Tags: python, python-requests

Hej to all.

Need help. I need send request, if request link not correct - I need to recive false but something wrong in the code. Can someone help ?

```html
from urllib.error import HTTPError
import requests

def form_url(urlcheck):
    try:
        y = requests.get(urlcheck)
    except HTTPError:
        return False
    if y == 200 or 403:
        return True


print(form_url("https://stackoverflow.com/"))

print(form_url("https://stackoverflowFALSE.com/")) # WRONL LINK NEED RECEVE FALSE
```

Comment: do `except requests.exceptions.RequestException:`

Comment: Thanks. You are best. All working .!!!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct way to try/except using Python requests module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511337/correct-way-to-try-except-using-python-requests-module)

Comment: Yes. Much more information with details and explanation. Thanks a lot.