# Webscraping with BeautifulSoup AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, pycharm, attributeerror, nonetype

I need your help.
Where did I a mistake in a code? I'm trying to scrap a website with BeautifulSoup:
[image]

Could you help me to fix and solve this problem?

I checked my code, tried to fix the problem, but I can't find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

use try except or check response status code

```html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests


def main():
    url = 'https://subslikescript.com/movies'
    root = 'https://subslikescript.com'
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        soup = bs(response.content, 'lxml')
        box = soup.find('article', class_='main-article')
        links = []
        for link in box.find_all('a',href=True):
            links.append(link['href'])

        #print(links)
        for link in links:
            response = requests.get(f"{root}/{link}")
            if response.status_code == 200:
                soup = bs(response.content, 'lxml')
                box = soup.find('article', class_='main-article')
                title = box.find('h1')
                if title:
                    print(title)
            else:
                print(link, response.status_code)
    else:
        print(response.status_code)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but when I try to use your version, I get the same error.

Comment: Try to create a new project, paste my code and run it

Comment: I found I get that error because the link to 'movie/Blind_Detective-2332707' seems to be broken on the target website. Maybe you know how to exclude this movie link and run the code with others links?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511337/correct-way-to-try-except-using-python-requests-module