# Where does a python requests connection failure issue from?

Tags: python, python-requests, try-except

I'm trying to check some endpoints by looping over urls in a python script using the requests module.

I have a simple function I call to check each endpoint:

```py
# Return endpoint status
def get_endpoint_status(url):
    response - requests.get(
        url,
        headers-headers,
        proxies-proxies,
        timeout 10
    )
    return response
```

And I have main code like this to loop over the environment hostname urls:

```py
# Main loop
for environment in environments_list:
environment_hostname - environment [0]
    # Get endpoint status
    r - get_endpoint_status('https://' + environment_hostname + endpoint)
    # If good
    if r.status_code = 200:
        print (r.status_code)
        print (r.url)
    # If not good
    else:
        print ("Failed")
        print (r.status_code)
        print (r.url)
```

I only care about 200 or fail http codes, so anything that is not 200 is a fail.

This script works fine when the endpoints return valid http codes.

But sometimes other things happen, like a request timeout or connection failure. for example. Then the script fails and exits and the results output stops.

I know I need to add some error handling, but I'm not sure what to try to catch or where to catch it?

1. Am I trying to catch a requests failure? Or would this failure be from the OS networking?
2. If there is a timeout or a connection failure of some kind and I catch it, can I then just make it return it as a http 500 status code and carry on with the script?

Sorry for all the questions, I'm not a python developer so this is all quite new to me

Comment: Related: [Correct way to try/except using Python requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511337/correct-way-to-try-except-using-python-requests-module).

Comment: Is that correct python? Why do you use - instead of =?

Comment: BTW `Am I trying to catch a requests failure? Or would this failure be from the OS networking?` It doesn't matter to you, you just want to catch errors. So a general `try except` is enough, log all the exceptions and once you have a few you can start adding `except`s for specific exceptions and execute different code based on that.