# Requests exception with API failure message

Tags: exception, python-requests

I'm making a request to an API using python requests. The best practice to raise an exception is with the `raise_from_status` method on the response object, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511337/correct-way-to-try-except-using-python-requests-module).

Assuming the API returns some helpful error message in the json or text of the response, what is the recommended way to handle this? My aim is to return this in the error trace so that errors can be more easily identified.

Extending the example from the accepted answer in the link above:

An example:

```py
try:
    r = requests.get('http://www.google.com/nothere', params={})
    r.raise_for_status()
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
    raise SystemExit(err)
```

```
404 Client Error: Not Found for url: http://www.google.com/nothere
```

Assume the body of the response has the message says `"No data for a undefined date range. Please provide 'start_date'."`.

A successful query might have the parameter:

```py
params = {'start_date': "2022-01-01"}
```